# Material UI SVG Problems

Tags: reactjs, electron, material-ui

I have problems with SVG Icons from Material UI Framework. The Problem is that icons don't render. Simple exemple:

```
<FloatingActionButton onTouchTap={this.handleToggle} style={menuIconStyle}>
  <NavigationMenu />
</FloatingActionButton>
```

And what I get:
[menu button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu0m3.png)

Or

[checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuUv1.png)

I use material-ui with react + electron.

Specification:

- electron: ^1.4.15
- material-ui: ^0.17.0
- react: ^15.4.2
- react-dom: ^15.4.2

Any ideas ?

Comment: r u using material ui theme `getMuiTheme` and `MuiThemeProvider`??

Comment: I am using this: <MuiThemeProvider>
      <AppRouter history={history} />
    </MuiThemeProvider>

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to define the `getMuiTheme`, use it like this:

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';


<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
  ....
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: only this Attempted to load extension "React Developer Tools" that has already been loaded.
2017-03-26 19:08:38.478 Electron Helper[14996:279562] Couldn't set selectedTextBackgroundColor from default ()